# URL redirect based on date and time

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect to an external dynamic url, one which contains today’s month, date, day, hour. E.g. `http://url.com/20170706-2200-048.mp3`

I read that using the .htaccess file and mod_rewrite I could use something like `http://url.com/news/%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}-%{TIME_HOUR}-048.mp3`.

How would I set this up in htaccess? And is there a way I could set a custom timezone? I.e. to EST or NZT.

Answer (score -1):

There have two variants.

First one is:

```
php_value date.timezone 'Region/Zone'
```

The second one is:

```
SetEnv TZ America/Washington
```

And you can use the time for redirect something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /news/%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}-%{TIME_HOUR}.mp3 [R=301,L]
```

I did not test it and am not sure it works.